# UNIX: How do I output data from 2 files using a loop structure?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Good afternoon everyone, I have a project I am working on, but I am having a bit of trouble with it. I am supposed to create a script that uses a loop structure to output data from 2 data files.

These are the two data files:

data1:

```
Dave,7348389800
Bob,3131234567
Carol,2483445576
Mary,3134491390
Ted,2484962204
Alice,6165564458
```

data2:

```
Bob,tuesday
Carol,friday
Ted,sunday
Alice,wednesday
Dave,thursday
Mary,saturday
```

This is how it is supposed look when i display it:

```
Day       Name     Phone
__________________________________________
MONDAY     Nobody
TUESDAY    Bob    (313) 123-4567
WEDNESDAY  Alice  (616) 556-4458
THURSDAY   Dave   (734) 838-9800
FRIDAY     Carol  (248) 344-5576
SATURDAY   Mary   (313) 449-1390
SUNDAY     Ted    (248) 496-2204
```

This is my current code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for day in monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
    do
    day=`grep -i day data2 |cut -d "," -f 2 `
    name=`cut -d "," -f 1 data1 `
    phone=`cut -d "," -f 2 data1`
done
echo  $day $name $phone >>output
```

And this is the output I am getting:

```
Day Name Phone
==============
tuesday friday sunday wednesday thursday saturday Dave Bob Carol Mary Ted Alice 7348389800 3131234567 2483445576 3134491390 2484962204 6165564458
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use the same variable `day` for both the iteration and the variable inside the loop;

Comment: `grep -i day` should be `grep -i $day`

Comment: You are echoing *after* the loop not in it so you only get to create output once. You aren't quoting your variables so the newlines in the values are being lost (you don't want the newlines in the first place so this is a second-order problem). You aren't selecting individual lines from the files in the loop you are getting the fields from *every* line every time.

Comment: Look on this site for questions about merging files based on column fields. There are many of them.

Comment: Ok I'm updating the code now. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `name=$(grep -i $day data2 | cut -d "," -f1)`? You already know the day, you need the name of the person scheduled for that day.

Comment: `awk` would be a better tool for this, you wouldn't have to grep the file each time through the loop. Just read each file into arrays, and then do array lookups.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the awk tool, and I am required to use a loop structure. I made the changes to my code though, and the names are correctly alligned with the days they're scheduled to work. I used {phone=`grep -i *, project2.phone|cut -d "," -f 2 project2.phone`} to try and align the phone numbers but to no avail. Also thank you for the input @Etan Reisner I will take a look at those questions.

Comment: Consider using `join`.  Note that you have to case-convert the day names, reformat the phone numbers, align the columns, find a way to present the days in the right sequence, add header lines, and nicely align the columns.  It isn't clear cut that using `join` is best; I'd probably go with Perl or Python though Awk is sufficient.  I would probably not go about it with nested loops in Bash.

Comment: @Jonathan I appreciate the insight, but I am required to use a loop structure, and I am not too familiar with the awk tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, using `printf` to get neatly formatted columnar output:

```
format="%-9s  %-9s  %s\n"

printf "$format" Day Name Phone
printf "$format" Day Name Phone | sed 's/./-/g'

for day in monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
do
    who=$(grep -i "$day" data2 | cut -d "," -f 1)
    if [ -z "$who" ]
    then
        who="NOBODY"
        phone=""
    else
        phone=$(grep -i "$who" data1 | sed 's/^[^,]*,\(...\)\(...\)\(....\)/(\1) \2-\3/')
    fi
    printf "$format" $(echo "$day" | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z') "$who" "$phone"
done
```

You could investigate `typeset -u uday="$day"` and then pass `"$uday"` to the `printf`; that doesn't seem to be an option in Bash 3.x, but it works in Korn shell and in [Bash 4.x](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) (for big enough values of x).  *[…Thinking about it, the `grep | cut` and `grep | sed` sequences could (and probably should) be replaced by pure `sed`, which is tidier still. You could also avoid the repeated `printf` to deal with the heading by using `sed 'p;s/./-/g'`.  Fixing those issues is left as an exercise for the reader…]*

Output:

```
Day        Name       Phone
---------------------------
MONDAY     NOBODY     
TUESDAY    Bob        (313) 123-4567
WEDNESDAY  Alice      (616) 556-4458
THURSDAY   Dave       (734) 838-9800
FRIDAY     Carol      (248) 344-5576
SATURDAY   Mary       (313) 449-1390
SUNDAY     Ted        (248) 496-2204
```

Comment: Nicely done -- and a heck of a lot shorted than using a `while` loop... e.g. `while read -u 4 line1 && read -u 5 line2; do <stuff>; done 4< "$1" 5< "$2"`.

Comment: WOW! I can't thank you enough man. This works perfectly. The only problem is {format="%-9s  %-9s  %s\n"} shows up between each row. I'm gonna look over my code, maybe I missed something. I can't thank you enough though. Sadly, my reputation is too low, so I can't upvote your answer.

Comment: If you copied my code verbatim, I don't see how that can happen.  I omitted the shebang, but that shouldn't be a factor in it.  Did you see curly braces too?  (You can include `code` in a comment by enclosing it in back quotes `` `code` ``, but getting back quotes into a comment is horrifyingly painful; I keep forgetting how to do it reliably.)

Comment: You used `print` instead of `printf` near the end.  You only need one set of I/O redirection; wrap the whole script with `{` at the top and `} > project2.output` at the bottom (both on lines of their own).  Or better, just run the script and redirect its output: `ksh schedule.sh > project2.output`.  Don't put unnecessary redirections in the code.

Comment: I'm having trouble with with pasting the code, but no, it doesn't have those curly braces. I only included those because I thought that was how you input code.

Comment: Ah ok, such a silly mistake. Also, thanks for the tip on redirection. I was not aware of that method. Again though, thank you. I can't say that enough man.

Comment: You cannot really control formatting in comments.  If it's your question or answer, it is best to update it with new material when it matters.  Or enclose the code fragment (it had better be small) in back-quotes.  When you had your script in a comment, I am almost sure I saw a `print "$format" "$day" "$who" "$phone"` type line at the bottom, instead of `printf "$format" "$day" "$who" "$phone"`, which might account for the trouble.  I also saw repeated use of `>>` to redirect which is what I'm counselling against.  Simply run the script and redirect all its output to the file.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I have corrected those mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS="\t" '
     BEGIN{split("1monday 2tuesday 3wednesday 4thursday 5friday 6saturday 7sunday",days," ")} 
   NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {b[$2]=$1} 
       END{for(i in days) {
            d=substr(days[i],2,length(days[i])-1); 
            dp=toupper(days[i]); 
            if(b[d]) 
               print dp,b[d],a[b[d]]; 
            else 
               print dp,"Nobody"}}' data1 data2 
 | sort | cut -c2- | column -t 
 | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4}$)/(\1) \2-\3/'


MONDAY     Nobody
TUESDAY    Bob     (313) 123-4567
WEDNESDAY  Alice   (616) 556-4458
THURSDAY   Dave    (734) 838-9800
FRIDAY     Carol   (248) 344-5576
SATURDAY   Mary    (313) 449-1390
SUNDAY     Ted     (248) 496-2204
```